# Shortcut to a problem based on toppling using D'Alemberts Principle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, statics

I found this question on this very site and was curious on how to solve it using D'Alembert's Principle

Here's the link to OP([link)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/287465/solving-a-problem-using-newtonian-mechanics-and-dalembert-principle)
[image]

.I already know how to do it by balancing the torque about toppling point so please don't post the latter as an answer .

My attempt was to displace the upper sphere by $d\theta$ which gives its virtual displacement as

[image]

$-rd{\theta}cos(\theta) \hat{j}$(notice we are only interested in the y component becuz the only component of the applied force which is gravity in this case is the y component in the dot product the other components vanish)

similarly the cylinder is also displaced $+r'd{\phi}cos(\phi) \hat{j}$ where r' is the distance from the point of toppling of the center of mass.

$$r'cos(\phi)=H/2=r(1+sin(\theta))$$

$$r'sin(\phi)=R=r(1+cos(\theta))$$
and
$$tan(\phi)=H/2R$$

the equation coming from D'Alemberts principle is
$mgrcos(\theta)d\theta=Mgr'cos(\phi)\phi$

I tried solving this but couldn't arrive at the right answer.

Any help would be appreciated!

[NOTE-I asked this question yesterday and couldn't get an answer and out of the fear that the previous question would get lost in the torrential flow of question
I have reposted please tolerate this once,as soon as I get an answer on either of the posts I will delete the other]

Comment: Please use double dollars to enclose equation. Thank you.

Comment: please help.I don't need a solution just a hint will be fine.

Comment: Duplicate of recent question by the same user :  [D'Alemberts Principle to solve a Classical Mechanics problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/592933/dalemberts-principle-to-solve-a-classical-mechanics-problem)

Comment: Please do not post the same question more than once. If you think that it has been forgotten about you can bring it back to the top of the Home Page of questions by making an edit to the question. eg Add further explanation to the text, especially if requested in the comments.